# Running ExecuteScriptProcessor in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm try to run a ExecuteScript processor in nifi which has a very simple python code in it

```
>>> g = open("/data/test.dat", 'rb')
>>> g.seek(143, 1)
>>> g.read(6)
```

But, nothing is happening. I'm new to Nifi so, don't know what I'm doing wrong

Thats my nifi job :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0rJK.png)

And that's my ExecuteScript processor:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM98V.png)

Can someone help me on that?

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922

Comment: start your processor ?

Comment: @daggett I tried that, but, as I'm new to nifi, didn't work for me

Comment: @maximeG I did that, the fact that you don't see that doesn't mean I didn't start it....

Comment: Your code is not for executescript processor. You have to rework your script according to examples from link I provided. Or if you have python installed, you could use executeprocess to run simple code like you have.

Comment: It's worth reading the documentation - ExecuteScript is supposed to handle FlowFiles using scripts, not for general scripting. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html

Write a script in a file on the NiFi Node OS and execute it with ExecuteProcess or ExecuteStreamCommand if you want to run that kind of script.